# python format with leading zeros and sign

Tags: python

I'm trying to format float numbers with left leading zeros and sign, but can't find a way to combine operators:

I need this:

```
-153.3 --> -00000153.30
```

I'm using this expression:

```
"{value:0>+{width}.{precision}f}".format(value=float(-153.3), width=12, precision=2)
```

But I'm getting this:
00000-153.30

Can't find the right way to put the "+" operator, can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, you're right, got a typo on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

Reading carefully the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) as I should have done!

```
"{value:+0{width}.{precision}f}".format(value=float(-153.3), width=12, precision=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> -153.3 --> 00000153.30

If the final numeric string should always be unsigned, why not just use `abs()` function:

```
val=-153.3
print("{value:0>{width}.{precision}f}".format(value=abs(val), width=11, precision=2))
```

The output:

```
00000153.30
```

Comment: Sorry, the expected output must include the sing, I had a typo on the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = -153.3
>>> str(a).zfill(10)
'-0000153.3'
```

If you want to print positive signs as well, one solution might be:

```
>>> a = +153.3
>>> '{0:+}'.format(a).zfill(10)
'+0000153.3'
```

The latter one also works for negative signs.

Comment: Sorry, the expected output must include the sing, besides the precision and lenght must be set as variables.

Comment: @kothvandir: Are you looking for something like `width=12; '{:+.{precision}f}'.format(-153.3, precision=2).zfill(width)` ?

Comment: just create a lambda that handles precision and witdh